# An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, video-capture, emgucv

I'm getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'as given below in my code. The video file I have given is 91 MB of size and my RAM is 4 GB (OS - Windows 32 bit)

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Emgu.CV.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

```
 private static List<Image<Bgr, Byte>> GetVideoFrames(String Filename)
        {
            List<Image<Bgr, Byte>> image_array = new List<Image<Bgr, Byte>>();
            Capture _capture = new Capture(Filename);

            bool Reading = true;

            while (Reading)
            {
                Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.QueryFrame();
                if (frame != null)
                {
                    image_array.Add(frame.Copy());
                }
                else
                {
                    Reading = false;
                }
            }

            return image_array;
        }
```

Can this be an issue with the video file size? What can I do to fix this issue?